# Trapezoid Integration in Scilab - Polygon Color Fill Stops

Tags: plot, polygon, scilab, numerical-integration

I have been working on a program in Scilab that numerically integrates a function by the trapezoidal rule (without using the built-in function). I have no problem with the integration or plotting the function, but I want to overlay the real function on a plot of the trapezoids, colored in.

For some reason, when I set the bounds a = 0 to b = 3, no problem, I get exactly what I want. However, when I set the bounds above 3, the trapezoids will still plot (by lines), but they won't be colored in. In the code below, the color stops at 3. If I plot 0 to 6, for example, the color stops half-way through. 3 to 6, and there is no color at all.

Here are the relevant sections of code:

```
deff('[y] = f(x)','y = e^(x^2)');            // Definition of function
a = 0;                                       // Lower bound
b = 4;                                       // Upper bound
n = 20;                                      // Number of intervals
h = ((b - a)/n);                             // Interval spacing
x = a:h:b;                                   // Array of positions for division
```

and

```
for i = 1:n+1
    y(i) = f(x(i));
end
```

and

```
for i = 1:n                                         // Plot colored trapezoids
    x_start = a+(h*(i-1));
    x_end = a+(h*(i));
    y_start = y(i);
    y_end = y(i+1);
    xpts = [x_start, x_end, x_end, x_start];
    ypts = [y_start, y_end, 0, 0];
    xfpoly(xpts,ypts,3);
end
```

[This is the plot output for a = 0, b = 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YZ7Y.jpg)

Comment: Well for starters 3 is not a legal value for close in xfpoly

Comment: @awiebe No, it is legal: that must be an integer, the color used to fill the polygon (please see Scilab help for more details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Scilab are you using?
I tried your code with Scilab 5.4.1 (64bit) and I got uncolored trapezoids, but with 5.5.2 (64bit) all the shapes are nice green.
So maybe there was some bugfix between these versions.
I also changed your function definition from `'y = e^(x^2)'` to `'y = %e^(x^2)'` since the Euler number is a predefined variable (at least in 5.5.2).

```
clc;
clear;

deff('[y] = f(x)','y = %e^(x^2)');            // Definition of function
a = 0;                                       // Lower bound
b = 6;                                       // Upper bound
n = 100;                                      // Number of intervals
h = ((b - a)/n);                             // Interval spacing
x = a:h:b;                                   // Array of positions for division


for i = 1:n+1
    y(i) = f(x(i));
end

scf(0);
clf(0);
plot2d(x,y);

for i = 1:n                                         // Plot colored trapezoids
    x_start = a+(h*(i-1));
    x_end = a+(h*(i));
    y_start = y(i);
    y_end = y(i+1);
    xpts = [x_start, x_end, x_end, x_start];
    ypts = [y_start, y_end, 0, 0];
    xfpoly(xpts,ypts,3);
end
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response (final exams).

I finally got around to downloading the latest version, and as you said it comes out looking nice. I was using 5.4.1 before, and now with 5.5.2 there aren't any problems!

I really appreciate your help. Thanks!